# Set Unity3D AnimationClip Property Without Resetting the Animator

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I'm trying to drive the animation of a Unity3D Mecanim rig based on live data from a Leap Motion Controller. I have 2 layers masking out everything but the hands in a Mecamim Human rig, on top of a base layer driving the rest of the rig. Both "hand layers" reference the same Animation Clip.

When I set the curve of a property in the clip using:

```
leftClip.SetCurve ("", typeof(Animator), "LeftHand.Index.1 Stretched", new AnimationCurve (new Keyframe (0, CurrentPosition), new Keyframe (0.5f, CurrentPosition)));
```

All currently playing states in the animator reset their playback creating a rather unhelpful jittery effect.

I'm getting a reference to the clip via the animator's `runtimeAnimatorController` property so I've got a reference to the runtime instance of the clip and not the asset.

I'd like to avoid going the route of overriding Mecanim in `LateUpdate()` due to the probability of race conditions with other LateUpdate-ing code and wanting to take advantage of Mecanim's animation tools in the rest of our pipeline.

Is there a method by which I can set a property in an animation clip at runtime without resetting the state playback? Specifically I need to set the Mecanim Humanoid Avatar muscle values.

Answer (score 0):

I've been in touch with Unity's support folks and it is in fact not possible in the current API (5.0.x) to set the curve of a property in a clip during the run of that clip without the Animator resetting.

I'm currently exploring a few ways to work around this restriction. Will update this answer when I've figured out how we'll handle it.